# If an Exception is thrown in a List<T>.ForEach, does the iteration stop?

Tags: c#, exception, foreach

If I have the following code:

```
List<MyClass> list = GetList();
list.ForEach(i => i.SomeMethod());
```

and let's say `SomeMethod()` throws an exception. Does `ForEach` continue iterating, or does it just stop right there?

If it does terminate, is there any way to get the rest of the items in the collection to run their methods?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, if an exception is thrown, the loop exits. If you don't want that behaviour, you should put exception handling into your delegate. You **could** easily create a wrapper method for this:

```
public static Action<T> SuppressExceptions<T>(Action<T> action)
{
    return item =>
    {
        try
        {
            action(item);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Log it, presumably
        }
    };
}
```

To be honest, I would *try* to avoid this if possible. It's unpleasant to catch *all* exceptions like that. It also doesn't record the items that failed, or the exceptions etc. You really need to think about your requirements in more detail:

- Do you need to collect the failed items?
- Do you need to collect the exceptions?
- Which exceptions do you want to catch?

It would almost certainly be cleaner to create a separate method which used the normal `foreach` loop instead, handling errors and collecting errors as it went. Personally I generally prefer using `foreach` over `ForEach` - you may wish to read [Eric Lippert's thoughts on this too](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

It will throw an error. You're also well on your way to reimplementing `foreach`. How about just:

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
    try
    {
        // dangerous thing with item
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // how do you want to log this?
    }
}
```

This has the benefit of working in most versions of .NET and being obviously side-effectful. Of course, you can put this code directly in the `ForEach` delegate, but I would only suggest that if it's going to be a method itself (rather than a lambda function).

---

A reasonable alternative is to create your own `ForEachWithCatch` extension that captures all the exceptions and sends them back to the caller:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T,Exception>> ForEachWithCatch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> action)
{
    var exceptions = new List<Tuple<T,Exception>>();

    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        try
        {
            action(item);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            exceptions.Add(Tuple.Create(item, e));
        }
    }

    return exceptions;
}
```

This sends back an enumerable of each item that failed and it's corresponding exception.

Comment: Tuple named: `List<(T Item, Exception ExceptionForItem)>`

Answer (score 0):

If your `SomeMethod` has implemented try-catch block then foreach will continue

```
void SomeMethod()
{
  try
  {
    //Some operation on i 
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
  }
}
```

But if not then foreach will break.

One what of doing it is this way

```
list.ForEach(i => 
     {
         try
         {
             i.SomeMethod();
         }
         catch(Exception ex)
         {
         }
     });
```

But its always good to have zero try-catch blocks in your code. Else you will never find where the culprit is.